# ODBC Connection on different subnets?

Tags: sql-server, connection, odbc

I am trying to establish a ODBC connection between 2 machines. When I go through the ODBC wizard for SQL Server, the server drop down does not populate. The IP address of my sql server say is 162.11.0.8 and the IP address of the machine I am trying to setup ODBC is 162.11.100.40. Is there any way to establish this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the protocol for searching for servers uses UDP so it won't cross networks. You can however connect across networks so long as you know the IP address and port (just enter them yourself).

Comment: Ok, I can ping the SQL server fine using the IP. WHat port would I use?

Comment: I'd start by trying port 1433 but you need to ask your server admin - it does not have to be 1433.